# Shinyapps.io will not render image but RStudio previewer does

Tags: r, shiny

To test how well a similarity algorithm I wrote works I created a shiny app to allow people to explore the output of the data.

It is fairly simple a drop down list allows the user to select a hotel and the matches from the data set are returned. So there is a visual aspect to the similarity I'm pulling a hero image from a website and displaying it under the hotel names (see image it is clear). This works well in the RStudio app preview.

[image: App running in RStudio previewer]

But when I deploy the app with shinyapps.io I get the following:

[image: Not working on shinyapps.io]

Here is the code that renders the image:

```
  HotelSim2Image <- eventReactive(input$findhotels, {
    url <- paste0('https://www.abcdef.com%2FHotel%2FSearch%3FhotelId%3D1870464', HotelSimilarity[HotelSimilarity$HotelName == input$hname, ]$Sim2)
    html <- paste(readLines(url), collapse="\n")
    matched <- str_match_all(html, "https.*xxx.com.*jpg")
    src = matched[[1]][4]
    tags$img(src=src, height = 150, width = 175)
  })
```

It finds the image source in the html and selects a specific one. I render this using uiOutput().

Any idea why the images are not displaying correctly on shinyapps?

Comment: Instead of downloading the image on the fly which seems unnecessary, download it to your computer and upload it to shinyapps.io along with your R code as usual.

Comment: The full data set it about 150K hotels hence why I am doing it dynamically.

Comment: Actually no, the fact that you have 150K images to download is a very strong argument for the opposite. For every user and session, the app has to download again and again and again... very slow and bandwidth consuming etc.